# QPython on android 5 and 6

Tags: android, qpython

There has been a hype on the issue of QPython incompatibility with Android 5 and 6. Nevertheless, QPython is distributed currently on Google Play without explicit  limitations on Android version.
Does it mean that a QPython script tested on Android 4 will work on Android 5/6 smoothly?